# How to create an MKCoordinate region similar to 50 miles radius in ios Swift?

Tags: swift, geolocation, cllocationmanager, mkcoordinateregion

I'm trying to create a region similar to a circle radius using CLLocation.  I understand radius logic and how its measured in meters, but not so clear on a MKCoordinate region and how long delta and lat delta translate to area.  I would like to get a 75 mile region. Here is my code....

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
```

If you could please provide an explanation more than just a short answer it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to create an actual circular region:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
let radius: CLLocationDistance = 60350.4    // meters for 37.5 miles
let regionIdentifier = "CircularRegion"     // any desired String

let circularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: regionIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/1452245-mkcoordinateregionmakewithdistan) function:

> Creates a new MKCoordinateRegion from the specified coordinate and
>   distance values.

```
func MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
_ centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, 
_ latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance, 
_ longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance) -> MKCoordinateRegion
```

> **centerCoordinate** - The center point of the new coordinate region.
>
> **latitudinalMeters** - The amount of north-to-south distance (measured in meters) to use for the span.
>
> **longitudinalMeters** - The amount of east-to-west distance (measured in meters) to use for the span.

So you will have something like:

```
let rect = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 50 * 1609.34, 50 * 1609.34)
```

Comment: Why do you us 50 * 1609.34 to make latitude and longitude distance in meters?

Comment: @CharlesJr: 1609.34 is 1 mile in meters, so Avt is converting your 50 miles to the meters equivalent used for `CLLocationDistance`.